# Convert Memo to Text

Tags: ms-access, unicode, text, memo

I've got an msaccess database which have been created in Access 2002. I only have access 2003 and 2008 in my computer. so I've converted the database into access 2003 format.

The problem I have is that I have a table named  `tblItms_F001`  in the database with a column named `stemtext` which is in memo datatype.
I just want to be able to read the text inside that column in every row. (have around 150 rows only). 
Moreover I don't know VB and haven't used access before as database. I've used C#, Java and mssql and oracle.
 Please let me know how can I just be able to read that text. When I try to open the table in access datasheet view it shows the column with weird text into it. For example following text appears in the first row's column data:

```
    %,9m$>m,#m#9$94m
```

Comment: You do *not* have Access 2008 installed on your computer, since there is no such thing.

Comment: Your question is unclear. I have no idea what context you are trying to use the data from.

Answer (score 0):

A `memo` field can contain any binary data, so it depends what the field represents. Is it just being used for very large text fields?

Comment: Not very large text. It have got questions. A list of frequently asked quetions. That's what the field containts -- just questions which are usually not large than 256 characters

Comment: @Jay: if that's the case then the choice of memo field is interesting. A standard access 'string' field can hold up to 256 chars

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: You mean it can contain up to 255 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Jay,

The most likely possibility for the content in your memo field (based on the short bit of text you provided) is that it is an **Adobe PDF file.**

Comment: Why do you think it's a PDF?  PDF's start with ASCII %PDF, while his memo starts with %,9m.

Comment: if you google his string (or some of it), it has a high matching correlation with PDF, but maybe that's just a coincidence.