# Convert Memo to Text

Tags: ms-access, unicode, text, memo

> **Exact Duplicate of** : [Convert Memo to Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112954/convert-memo-to-text)

Hello, I've got an msaccess database which have been created in MS Access 97. I only have access 2003 and 2008 in my computer. so I've converted the database into access 2003 format.

The problem I have is that I have a table named 'tblItms_F001' in the database with a column named 'stemtext' which is in memo datatype. I just want to be able to read the text inside that column in every row. (have around 150 rows only). Moreover I don't know VB and haven't used access before as databse. I've used C#, Java and mssql and oracle. Please let me know how can I just be able to read that text. When I try to open the table in access datasheet view it shows the column with wierd text into it. For example following text appears in the first row's column data

%,9m$>m,#m#9$94m

Note : the field contains just questions which are usually not large than 256 characters

Comment: exact duplicate posted one (1) hour ago -- which has two (2) answers:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112954/convert-memo-to-text

Comment: @Jay: reposting your question multiple times will not get it answered any faster (probably the opposite in fact)

Comment: even after posting it twice I didn't get a proper answer of the question.

Comment: Then edit your original question to clarify.

Comment: The problem is that the question is completely unclear since you don't describe the context in which you're using the data and getting unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

Trying using/creating a repeating form instead of a datasheet view.  (It's been awhile, but I think the Form Wizard should make quick work of this).

Comment: As I stated above haven't used access or VB before. Would you please explain it  or suggest an article on how to do this ? Thanks for your response

Comment: Check out http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HP051876411033.aspx, or do some searches about "how to create a form in Access" -- should be a number of tutorials out there to get you started.

Comment: If you're not using Access, why are you tagging your question as MS-Access? If all you're using is Jet/ACE, then you need to reword your question to indicate that, as well as indicating what programming environment you are using to access the Jet/ACE data.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried creating a repeating form using MS Infopath but when I perform the query it gives the same text in the result textboxes. A text which appears like this :

%,9m$>m,#m#9$94m